# Delete lines in a file till a particular line

Tags: bash, shell

I want to solve this problem using shell scripts and looping concept

I have a text file (`file.txt`) having data like this:

```
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 156756737
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
ABC 123 hahah 18567737
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 167767
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
GXT 123 asdfg 0
```

and I want to delete the line from last line up to the line where the lines are starting with same name i.e `ABC`.

The expected output is:

```
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 156756737
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
ABC 123 hahah 18567737
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 167767
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
```

I don't care even if the line ending with zero is in the middle but it should not be in the last. Also I want to throw an error if the lines starting with uniform names are ending with `0`.

Example: `ABC 123 hahah 0`.

Comment: And what did you try? Please show your best coding attempt.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: The ask is to remove lines with duplicate name, but output shows 3 lines with ABC at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### using tac

If you have tac, you can do `tac|sed|tac`:

```
kent$  tac file|sed '0,/^ABC/{/^ABC/!d}'|tac
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 156756737
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
ABC 123 hahah 18567737
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 167767
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
```

### awk one-liner

You can also let awk read your file twice. Marking the last `ABC` line in the first go, then print the required lines in the 2nd go:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR&&/^ABC/{n=FNR;next}FNR<=n ' file file
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 156756737
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
FDC 123 hasddhs 0
ABC 123 hahah 18567737
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
ABC 123 hahah 167767
ABC 123 hahah 1897237
```

Comment: Than you very much buddy....its working..If you don't mind can you please explain the logic so that I can understand this command

Comment: @Akcs004 which part you don't understand?

Comment: {n=FNR;next}FNR<=n - This one and why should we give 'file file' twice

Comment: @Akcs004 I noted in answer, we are about to read the file twice. I would suggest picking some awk tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a rough idea, but this isn't a complete solution, because I don't feel that there is really enough information here.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

sed -n '/ABC/p' file >> file1
```

This just prints all of the lines containing "ABC" and writes them into a new file.  If that is all you want, you can then just use mv to overwrite the original file with the new one.

Comment: this is not what OP is looking for.